# Visit all houses in $m \times n$ town

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose a town is an $m \times n$ grid of houses, how many ways is there to visit every house exactly once, if one is only allowed to visit one of the (max 4) neighbouring houses in 1 step?

How many if one requires the starting and ending path to be a house on the edge of town?

And how many if one is allowed to visit any of 8 neighbouring houses? (Path should not cross itself.)

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you’re essentially asking whether there is a finite set of non-deterministic finite state automata from which every possible non-deterministic finite state automaton can be built.

Comment: How is this an "edit"?  It's now a completely different question... plus, now @Brian's comment makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @mjqxxxx: Thanks for the heads-up. I’ll leave my previous comment up for a bit, in case the original question gets rolled back, but this is a bit disconcerting, to say the least.

Comment: I've answered the new question; I didn't see the original one.

Comment: Original question appeared on [cstheory.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9730/two-questions-on-finite-state-machines). Maybe the user had another question on their mind and instead of asking a new one, they recycled the one moved to cstheory.SE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No closed formula is known for the number of [Hamiltonian paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) or cycles on a rectangular lattice.

The following entries in OEIS are relevant to your questions: [A003763](https://oeis.org/A003763) (cycles on $2n\times 2n$ lattice), [A120443](https://oeis.org/A120443) (paths on $n \times n$ lattice), [A140519](https://oeis.org/A140519) (king tours on $n \times n$ board) and [A140521](https://oeis.org/A140521) (directed king tours on $n \times n$ board).

Here are a few papers that contain research related to this question: 
[1981](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2689376),
[1990](http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v42/i1/p660_1),
[1994](http://www.dmi.uns.ac.rs/NSJOM/Papers/24_1/NSJOM_24_1_261_267.pdf),
[1997](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9500330Y) and
[2007](http://iopscience.iop.org/1751-8121/40/49/003).